# Is it possible to use XDT inside C# projects?

Tags: c#, xslt, xdt-transform

I have XMLs in database table that need to transform updating values, simple changes, depending on certain conditions.

Did my research but only found tools/plug-ins to apply to Web.Config or App.Config:

http://ctt.codeplex.com/

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

I could use XSLT but XDT seems ideal, simpler, but how can I use it inside my C# project?

Thanks

Comment: XDT may seem simpler but in my experience when you try to use a tool for a purpose it wasn't designed for, you are inevitably going to run into problems. If your goal is to transform XML structures, XSLT is designed for exactly that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end found a nice piece of code that does what I wanted:

http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2010/09/20/microsoft-xdt-language/

http://code.google.com/p/xdt/

Answer (score 7):

For anyone coming across this post, there is a NuGet package providing the ability to perform this transformation:

> Install-Package Microsoft.Web.Xdt

Then, it's something along the lines of:

```
// Some example file paths
var sourceDoc = "web.config";
var transDoc = "web.Debug.config";
var destDoc = "bin\web.config";

// The translation at-hand
using (var xmlDoc = new XmlTransformableDocument())
{
  xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
  xmlDoc.Load(sourceDoc);

  using (var xmlTrans = new XmlTransformation(transDoc))
  {
    if (xmlTrans.Apply(xmlDoc))
    {
      // If we made it here, sourceDoc now has transDoc's changes
      // applied. So, we're going to save the final result off to
      // destDoc.
      xmlDoc.Save(destDoc);
    }
  }
}
```

That is, of course, very basic with minimal checking, but it gives you the gist.

Comment: Hi, What other kinds of checking do you think might be needed?

Comment: @CRice: File validation (do one or both exist?), schema validation (is the markup valid?), security check (Do you have access to write to the target directory?), among others.